# Group hash values by key and concatenate values

Tags: ruby, hash

I need to group a hash by keys and concatenate the values. For example, given this hash:

```
[
  {"name": "FT002", "data": {"2017-11-01": 1392.0}},
  {"name": "FT004", "data": {"2017-11-01": 4091.0}},
  {"name": "FT002", "data": {"2017-12-01": 1279.0}},
  {"name": "FT004", "data": {"2017-12-01": 3249.0}}
]
```

I want to produce this hash:

```
[
  {"name": "FT002", "data": {"2017-11-01": 1392.0, "2017-12-01": 1279.0}},
  {"name": "FT004", "data": {"2017-11-01": 4091.0, "2017-12-01": 3249.0}}
]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I tried various iterations of `inject`, `group_by`, and `merge`, but can't seem to get the right result.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this in three short one-liners, first producing a hash mapping names to data, and then producing your desired structure:

```
data = [
  {"name":"FT002","data":{"2017-11-01":1392.0}},
  {"name":"FT004","data":{"2017-11-01":4091.0}},
  {"name":"FT002","data":{"2017-12-01":1279.0}},
  {"name":"FT004","data":{"2017-12-01":3249.0}}
]

hash = Hash.new { |hash,key| hash[key] = {} }

data.each { |name:, data:| hash[name].merge!(data) }

hash = hash.map { |k,v| { name: k, data: v } }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data.group_by { |h| h[:name] }.map do |k,arr|
  { name: k, data: arr.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h.update(g[:data]) } }
end
  #=> [{:name=>"FT002", :data=>{:"2017-11-01"=>1392.0, :"2017-12-01"=>1279.0}},
  #    {:name=>"FT004", :data=>{:"2017-11-01"=>4091.0, :"2017-12-01"=>3249.0}}]
```

The first step is to use [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) to produce the following hash.

```
data.group_by { |h| h[:name] }
  #=> {"FT002"=>[
  #               {:name=>"FT002", :data=>{:"2017-11-01"=>1392.0}},
  #               {:name=>"FT002", :data=>{:"2017-12-01"=>1279.0}}
  #             ],
  #    "FT004"=>[
  #               {:name=>"FT004", :data=>{:"2017-11-01"=>4091.0}},
  #               {:name=>"FT004", :data=>{:"2017-12-01"=>3249.0}}
  #             ]
  #   }
```

The second step is to simply manipulate the keys and values of this hash. See [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`).

An alternative to the second step is the following.

```
data.group_by { |h| h[:name] }.map do |k,arr|
  { name: k, data: arr.map { |g| g[:data].flatten }.to_h }
end
```

Note that this uses [Hash#flatten](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-flatten), not [Array#flatten](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten).

Answer (score -1):

This should generate the the results you're looking for:

```
data = [
  {"name":"FT002","data":{"2017-11-01":1392.0}},
  {"name":"FT004","data":{"2017-11-01":4091.0}},
  {"name":"FT002","data":{"2017-12-01":1279.0}},
  {"name":"FT004","data":{"2017-12-01":3249.0}}
]

newData = {}

data.each do |x|
  newData[x[:name]] = [] unless newData[x[:name]].present?
  newData[x[:name]].push x[:data]
end

combined = []
newData.each do |index,value|
  dateData = {}
  value.each do |dateStuff|
    dateStuff.each do |dateIndex, dateValue|
      dateData[dateIndex] = dateValue
    end
  end
  values = {"name": index, "data": dateData}
  combined.push values
end

combined
```

Comment: Awesome, that works well. I guess I was assuming there was a simple group function.  I put this into a separate function and it's working perfectly.  Thanks.